# Rails export to CSV file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, export-to-csv

It is partly working. It generates the file but the output is not how I want it.

Controller

```
@messages = Message.take(2)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data @messages.to_csv }
  end
```

Message.rb

```
def self.to_csv
    CSV.generate do |csv|
          csv << Message.attribute_names
          Message.all.each do |message|
            csv << message.attributes.values
          end
    end
 end
```

I get the CSV file downloaded, it contains the records itself but it does not show the columns and values

```
#<Message:0x007fca7a028338>,#<Message:0x007fca79a6bf58>
```

I would expect the Message attributes like:

```
ID,text
1,hello
2,world
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Message.take(2)` returns Array. You need ActiveRecord::Relation.

Try `Message.limit(2)`